# How to get id of clicked item in ListView?

Tags: android-layout, listview

I am trying to implement deletion from database using Contextual Action Bar. When I implemented OnItemLongClickListener to retrieve the id of the clicked item, it returned the position value instead. Here's the code.
*This is my first question, so please excuse any typing errors*

```
public class ChecklistActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
ListDBHelper mHelper;
private long currentListItemIndex;
public int ids;
private CLAdapter mAdapter;
public ArrayList<String> taskList;
ListView lv;
private static final String TAG = "CheckListActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHelper=new ListDBHelper(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist);
    mAdapter=new CLAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_checklist_item,R.id.check_textView,taskList);

    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.item_listView);
    final Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null){
        ids=(int)extras.getLong("key_id");
    }
    updateUI((int)extras.getLong("key_id"));
    Button addButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            EditText addTask =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addTask);
            String list = String.valueOf(addTask.getText());
            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(ListContract.CheckListEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, list);
            values.put(ListContract.CheckListEntry.COLUMN_LIST_KEY,(int)extras.getLong("key_id"));
            db.insertWithOnConflict(ListContract.CheckListEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    null,
                    values,
                    SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
            db.close();
            addTask.setText("");
            updateUI((int)extras.getLong("key_id"));

        }
    });
   lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
       @Override
       public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           currentListItemIndex=id;
           lv.setItemChecked(position, !mAdapter.isPositionChecked(position));
           return false;
       }

   });}
  lv.setChoiceMode(lv.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    lv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        private int nr = 0;
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            if (checked) {
                nr++;
                mAdapter.setNewSelection(position, checked);
            } else {
                nr--;
                mAdapter.removeSelection(position);
            }
            mode.setTitle(nr + " selected");

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle("Remove Item");
            nr = 0;
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.checklist_cab_menu,menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.action_delete_item:
                    nr = 0;

                    deleteRow((int)currentListItemIndex);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
}


public void updateUI(int keyid){

    ListDBHelper mHelper=new ListDBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db= mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c= db.rawQuery("SELECT CheckListEntry.*,CheckListEntry._id as _id FROM CheckListEntry WHERE "+
             "CheckListEntry.ListKey == "+keyid+";",null);
    ArrayList<String> taskList=new ArrayList<>();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        int idx=c.getColumnIndex(ListContract.CheckListEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE);
        taskList.add(c.getString(idx));
        Log.d(TAG,"cursorRead"+c.getString(idx));
    }
        mAdapter = new CLAdapter(this,
                R.layout.activity_checklist_item,
                R.id.check_textView,
                taskList);
        lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

public void deleteRow(int id){
    ListDBHelper mHelper = new ListDBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db= mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(ListContract.CheckListEntry.TABLE_NAME,"_id =="+id+";",null);
    updateUI(ids);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a tag by using `setTag` method?

Answer (score 0):

Try `view.getId()` to get the id of the clicked view. The `id` argument is the row id. See [AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html#onItemLongClick(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)).

> **onItemLongClick**
>
> boolean onItemLongClick (AdapterView parent, 
>                   View view, 
>                   int position, 
>                   long id)
>
> Callback method to be invoked when an item in this view has been clicked and held. Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.
>
> Parameters
>
> parent     AdapterView: The AbsListView where the click happened
>
> **view     View: The view within the AbsListView that was clicked**
>
> position   int: The position of the view in the list
>
> **id   long: The row id of the item that was clicked**